# Turn off sound only in Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10, audio, microsoft-edge

Is there away to turn off all sound in Microsoft edge? Preferably something that is browser-wide, survives browser relaunches, and remains until I turn it back on.

Answer (score 2):

My co-workers tell me that they do it with the free [EarTrumpet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/eartrumpet/9nblggh516xp) app from the Microsoft Store:

```
EarTrumpet is a volume control app for both classic and modern Windows applications.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it turns off sound for all your browsers
https://www.thebalance.com/mute-sound-in-your-internet-browser-897051

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please remember that the OP emphasized that they want to mute the sound *only* within Edge.